# DB access from a Mapper in MapReduce

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, mapreduce, spark-streaming, distributed-computing

I planning the next generation of an analysis system I'm developing and I think of implementing it using one of the `MapReduce`/`Stream-Processing` platforms like `Flink`, `Spark Streaming` etc.

For the analysis, the mappers must have DB access.

So my greatest concern is when a mapper is paralleled, the connections from  the connection pool will all be in use and there might be a mapper that fail to access the DB.

How should I handle that?
Is it something I need to concern about?

Comment: I come from a Spark background. I think you should avoid giving your 'mappers' DB access, it causes complexity and in my opinion isn't the best approach to parallelized data analysis (with Spark at least). Are you investigating the best way to get data into your analysis pipeline?

Comment: For what do you need the DB access inside your computation processes? Data ingestion? Lookup?

Comment: @ImDarrenG, Yes, I'm investigating the best way to get data into the analysis pipeline. and @ LiMuBei, I need to process a lot of data from many sensors, each sample need to be processed using meta-data from DB (which may change from time to time, otherwise I would have cached all the data from DB in each mapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have pointed out, a pull-style strategy is going to be inefficient and/or complex.

Your strategy for ingesting the meta-data from the DB will be dictated by the amount of meta-data and the frequency that the meta-data changes. Either way, moving away from fetching the meta-data when it's needed, and toward receiving updates when the meta-data is changed, is likely to be a good approach.

Some ideas:

- Periodically dump the meta-data to flat file/s into distributed file system
- Streaming meta-data updates to your pipeline at write-time to keep an in-memory cache up-to-date
- Use a separate mechanism to fetch the meta-data, for instance Akka Actor/s polling for changes

It will depend on the trade-offs you are able to make for your given use-case.

If DB interactivity is unavoidable, I do wonder if map-reduce style frameworks would be the best approach to solve your problem.  But any failed tasks should be retried by the framework.